# Bubble Sort List of Items Using Code Not Sort Function

Tags: vb.net, sorting

Hi I have a project that requires me to bubble sort a list of patients. How can I do it using this code:

```
  Swapped = True
    While Swapped = True
        Swapped = False
        ComparisonNumber = 0
        While ComparisonNumber < PatientCount
            If Names(ComparisonNumber) > Names(ComparisonNumber + 1) Then
                Temp = Names(ComparisonNumber)
                Names(ComparisonNumber) = Names(ComparisonNumber + 1)
                Names(ComparisonNumber + 1) = Temp
                Swapped = True
            End If
            ComparisonNumber = ComparisonNumber + 1
        End While
    End While
```

where instead of Names() I have a list of items:

```
Public Class Patient

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property Height As Decimal

    Public Property Weight As Decimal
```

Comment: Wherever that original code compares two items from the Names list, you simply compare the Name properties of two items from your list, or whatever property(ies) you're sorting by.

Comment: Ok thanks, but what is the property in my list called? I try p.Names(ComparisonNumber) and it gives me p is not declared. Is p.names, p.height etc correct or is it something different

Comment: @Marcel What seems to be the problem here? Tell me about it and I'd be happy to help :) Does your code work? To make things a lot easier, you can remove your 'Swapped' variable and change the algorithm a bit. I've done this before and I can generate the code again anytime. But do tell the problem on your code first :)

Comment: Thanks for offering to help :), but I've switched back to using normal arrays for my project so I don't need a solution to this problem anymore

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you would have needed to implement your own bubble sort before but suddenly don't because you're now using an array.  You can sort any list by any criteria you want without implementing a sorting algorithm yourself.

Comment: I had to bubble sort either way, it is just easier for me with an array. I don't know how to bubble sort a list. Also it is for a school project so we have to use the algorithm not the function for obvious reasons.